# RuntimeError: working outside of application context

Tags: python, mysql, flask, werkzeug, flask-restful

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,jsonify,json,g
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

class TestMySQL():
    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
        try:
            g.db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', database='mysql')
        except mysql.connector.errors.Error as err:
           resp = jsonify({'status': 500, 'error': "Error:{}".format(err)})
           resp.status_code = 500
           return resp

    @app.route('/')
    def input_info(self):
        try:     
            cursor = g.db.cursor()
            cursor.execute ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testmysql (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, \
                     email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
            cursor.close()
```

**test.py**

```py
from app import *
class Test(unittest.TestCase):         
    def test_connection1(self):  
        with patch('__main__.mysql.connector.connect') as mock_mysql_connector_connect:
            object = TestMySQL()
            object.before_request()  # Runtime error on calling this
```

I am importing **app** into **test.py** for unit testing. On calling  '*before_request*' function into test.py, it is throwing a RuntimeError: `working outside of application context`, the same is happening on calling '*input_info()*'

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Flask has an [Application Context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context), and it seems like you'll need to do something like:

```
def test_connection(self):
    with app.app_context():
        #test code
```

You can probably also shove the `app.app_context()` call into a test setup method as well.

Comment: @brenns10 can you please tell more about this? Why does this happen?

Comment: @aks The linked page probably has a better explanation than I could give. Basically, the way Flask is designed, (1) code should be able to access a global variable containing the current Flask app object, but (2) multiple applications might exist in a single process. Flask manages this by setting up some variables before you handle a request. But when you're testing, you have to set up the "application context" yourself, so that your code can find the correct global variables.

Comment: I get this for using `jsonify`. It's really bad that a simple JSON conversion requires the app to run "in context".

Comment: @milosmns: jsonify is more than a simple json conversion though.  It actually builds a proper http response.  You can either use json.dumps() directly if you want a simple json conversion.  Otherwise I bet even flask.json.dumps will want the context.

Comment: @Eddie Parker: I guess that's exactly what I didn't like. I was expecting the basic (or better: default, well known) functionality to run without any additional requirements (like app context)... and then maybe compose on top of that by adding extra functionality (like HTTP) via some opt-in API. Maybe it's also a communication/documentation issue. I don't know what is being used more - plain JSON conversion or JSON+HTTP, so I could be wrong in assuming that most people want just plain conversion.

Comment: Yeah; I hear you.  When I started with flask I figured 'jsonify' just meant that: 'make this into json'.  If they renamed it to something like "make_json_response' it would fit better with what it does.

Comment: I got this issue when version chain is updated.

    Flask==2.1.3 ---> Flask==2.2.2
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1 ---> Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2

Especially the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` version upgrade brings this issue.

Answer (score 25):

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.app_context().push()

Run in terminal
    >python
    >>>from app import app
    >>>from app import db
    >>>db.create_all()

Now it should work
```

Answer (score 6):

I followed the answer from [@brenns10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820319/brenns10) when I ran into a similar problem when using `pytest`.

I followed the suggestion of putting it into test setup, this works:

```
import pytest
from src.app import app


@pytest.fixture
def app_context():
    with app.app_context():
        yield


def some_test(app_context):
    # <test code that needs the app context>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using python3.8 and had to use a small variation to the answers already posted. I included the the below in pytests and didn't have to change anything else in the rest of the test file.

```
from flask import Flask

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def app_context():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        yield
```

This can also be used with a context manager as well.
The main different to note here is the creation of the Flask app within the test file rather than it being imported from the main application file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I created a thread inside the app:

```
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=handle_offchain).start()
```

when flask app receives a request, Flask creates both the application context and the request context [Request Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/reqcontext/) to handle that particular request.

> The request context keeps track of the request-level data during a
> request. Rather than passing the request object to each function that
> runs during a request, the request and session proxies are accessed
> instead
>
> When the Flask application handles a request, it creates a Request
> object based on the environment it received from the WSGI server.
> Because a worker (thread, process, or coroutine depending on the
> server) handles only one request at a time, the request data can be
> considered global to that worker during that request. Flask uses the
> term context local for this.

This is [application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/)

> The application context keeps track of the application-level data
> during a request, CLI command, or other activity. Rather than passing
> the application around to each function, the current_app and g proxies
> are accessed instead.

Flask's context locals (current_app, request, etc.) are tied to the thread handling the current request, and they are not shared or available in other threads by default. If you create a separate thread manually within a route handler or view function, it won't automatically have access to the Flask application or request context.

```
     def handle_offchain(app_context):
        # this will give access to context
        app_context.push()
        ....
    
    # args will be passed to  `handle_offchain` method
    Thread(target=handle_offchain,args=[current_app.app_context()]).start()
```

Answer (score -1):

Running on the terminal is what was raising the error for me. To solve this, I  did 2 things;

1. Added the line below after defining `app.config[...]` and creating a `db` object;

   `app.app_context().push()`
2. On the terminal, I also imported `app` while doing imports from the application file;

   `from name_of_your_app import app`

Comment: This seems to be the same solution as provided in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74364913/5320906)?