# How to retrieve an image from redis in python flask

Tags: python, templates, flask, redis

I am trying to store an image in the redis and retrieve it and send it to an HTML template. I am able to cache the image but I dunno how to retrieve the image back and send it to the HTML template. This is the part of my code which does caching and retrieving.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import json
import redis
import urlparse
import os
from StringIO import StringIO
import requests
from PIL import Image
from flask import send_file

REDIS_URL = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://:@localhost:6379/'))
r = redis.StrictRedis(
            host=REDIS_URL.hostname, port=REDIS_URL.port,
            password=REDIS_URL.password)

class MovieInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, movie):
        self.movie_name = movie.replace(" ", "+")

    def get_movie_info(self):
        url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + self.movie_name + '&y=&plot=short&r=json'
        result = Request(url)
        response = urlopen(result)
        infoFromJson = json.loads(response.read())
        self._cache_image(infoFromJson)
        return infoFromJson

    def _cache_image(self, infoFromJson):
        key = "{}".format(infoFromJson['Title'])
        # Open redis.
        cached = r.get(key)
        if not cached:
            response = requests.get(infoFromJson['Poster'])
            image = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
            r.setex(key, (60*60*5), image)
            return True


    def get_image(self, key):
        cached = r.get(key)
        if cached:
           image = StringIO(cached)
           image.seek(0)
           return send_file(image, mimetype='image/jpg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    M = MovieInfo("Furious 7")
    M.get_movie_info()
    M.get_image("Furious 7")
```

Any help on the retrieving part would be helpful. Also whats the best way to send the image file from a cache to a HTML template in Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you saved in Redis is a string, 
Something likes:`'<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=300x475 at 0x4874090>'`.

`response.content` is rawData .  <del>use `Image.frombytes()` to get Image object.</del>

<del>Check here : [Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py)</del>

> You can't create nested structures in Redis, meaning you can't (for
>   example) store a native redis list inside a native redis hash-map.
>
> If you really need nested structures, you might want to just store a
>   JSON-blob (or something similar) instead. Another option is to store
>   an "id"/key to a different redis object as the value of the map key,
>   but that requires multiple calls to the server to get the full object.

Try this:

```
response = requests.get(infoFromJson['Poster'])
# Create a string buffer then set it raw data in redis.
output = StringIO(response.content)
r.setex(key, (60*60*5), output.getvalue())
output.close()
```

see: [how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py)

Comment: Sorry, am new to this. Am not able to get it. can you point me in my code where I should change it.

Comment: Hi I modified the caching part with your suggestion, but what I get is  RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context

Comment: I found this, [RuntimeError: working outside of application context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444036/runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context)

Comment: I fixed the runtime issue. This is my project repo https://github.com/arunraman/Code-Katas/tree/master/MovieLocator I am trying to get the image file from redis and push it to the HTML template, but the image_file is not coming up correctly. I am new to flask. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see `<img src= {{ image }}>` in your template.The **src** attribute specifies the URL (web address) of the image.So, `get_image()` return `infoFromJson['Poster']` will be ok.