# Flask application context error not solved with 'with' clausule

Tags: flask, neo4j, middleware, py2neo

I am attempting to create a **Flask** middleware in order to make **py2neo** transactions atomic. First I got a `working outside of application context` error, and I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444036/runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context) solution, as seen in the following code:

```
from flask import g
from py2neo import Graph

def get_db():
    return Graph(password="secret")

class TransactionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        with app.app_context():  # Error raises here.
            g.graph = get_db()
            g.transaction = g.graph.begin()

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        try:
            app_status = self.app(environ, start_response)
            # some code
            return app_status
        except BaseException:
            g.transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            g.transaction.commit()
```

But I got this error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'app_context'`.

I don't know if the solution I'm trying is not suitable for my case, or what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a WSGI middleware, so what gets passed in as an `app` is actually a method called `Flask.wsgi_app` the results of which you a later supposed to return from your `__call__` handler.

Perhaps you can simply import your actual flask app and use app_context on that, as in:

```
from app import app # or whatever module it's in

# and then
class TransactionMiddleware(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):   
        with app.app_context():
            ...
```

I would also consider just instantiating your `Graph` somehere on a module level. Perhaps next to your flask app instantiation and not attaching it to `g`. This way you can use it without application context:

```
# app.py
flask = Flask(__main__)
db = Graph(password="secret")
```

You can use it by directly importing:

```
# middleware.py
from app import db
```