# Flask `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` from Middleware

Tags: python, flask

Here is the Middleware class:

```
class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app


    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        cookies = request.cookies
        path = request.path

        environ['isAuthenticated'] = isAuthenticated(cookies)

        return self.app(environ, start_response)


def isAuthenticated(cookies):
    if (len(cookies)) > 0 :
        if 'jwt' in cookies:
            payload = decodeJWT(cookies['jwt'])
            connection = connect_db()
            
            
            return payload
    else:
        return False
```

And here is the `ConnectDB.py`:

```
def connect_db():
    host = current_app.config['HOST']
    db = current_app.config['DB']
    username = current_app.config['USERNAME']
    password = current_app.config['PASSWORD']
    
    connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=db, user=username, password=password, port=5432, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    return connection
```

I'm provoking the `middleware` likes this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('SETTINGS')
app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I know that I need to call `connect_db` from within the app context to access the DB credentials but how can I access it from inside the `Middleware` class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444036/runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to pass the `actual or` full`app into`Middleware`not just the`wsgi` like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('SETTINGS')
app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app, app)
```

and then `Middleware` becomes like this:

```
class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, wsgi, app):
        self.wsgi = wsgi
        self.app = app


    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        cookies = request.cookies
        path = request.path

        with self.app.app_context():
            environ['isAuthenticated'] = isAuthenticated(cookies)

        return self.wsgi(environ, start_response)
```