# encountering a RuntimeError in my Flask application

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, runtime

I'm encountering a RuntimeError in my Flask application, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving the issue. My Python file is named 'auth.py,' and it has a 'database.db' file located nearby.

Here's the error message I'm facing:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "path\to\auth.py", line 10, in <module>
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
...
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)



@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')



@ app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've confirmed that the 'database.db' file is present in the same directory as 'auth.py.' What could be causing this RuntimeError, and how can I resolve it?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Notice where the error happens and where you set `'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'
```

Before the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`.

Comment: thanks!!
but now i have an another problem, after i write 
>>> from auth import app, db
>>> db.create_all()
in the Python repl i have this error 
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...path_to_your_script...", line X, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  ...
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

`

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444036/runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context), this is Flask specific error.

Answer (score 1):

you should not initiate the db before setting the DB_PARAMS such as `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`. This is because `SQLAlchemy(app)` loads all the config variables.

In your case you are initializing the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` which tries to load the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`(which hadn't been set yet) so it you are seeing the error.

Updated code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey' # also move secret key to top. 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

# move here
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)



@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')



@ app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```